# how can i use destructuring inside a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, variable-assignment, destructuring

I want to use "destructuring assignment" inside of a class function to get ride of using "this" keyword multiple time...

but i got this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

my code is somthing like this:

```
class className {
        constructor() {
                this.a = 1;
                this.b = 2;
                this.c = 3;
        }
        function() {
                [a, b, c] = [this.a, this.b, this.c];
        }
}

let obj = new className;
obj.function();
```

(my purpose is to fill a 10*10 array with `a`, `b` and `c` so I prefer to use `a` instead of `this.a`)

Comment: You forgot to declare the variables. Use `const`.

Comment: `const [a, b, c] = [this.a, this.b, this.c];`

Comment: It works, thank you, but why outside of a class it is not necessary to declare variables?

Comment: @AminSanei Because a class body is strict by default. I strongly encourage you to move to [JavaScript modules](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) or at least enable [strict mode](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) everywhere.